# is it possible to merge multiple populations for hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, assumptions, population

so basically I want to test differences between two systems. I am collecting time needed for executing queries, every query was executed 50 times. I have defined some queries such as q1, q2... qn each query has some specific meaning for example queries q1,q2,q3 are aggregation queries, thus those are part of a group "aggregation queries". I want to compare two systems per group of queries not separately per every query. The question is how/if can I merge the results of multiple queries into one for preforming hypothesis test (Mann-Whitney U). I assume that every set of records per query is a separate population and should not be merged right?